# VBA: define a variable with a keypress

Tags: excel, vba, variable-assignment, keypress

I have a small VBA macro that runs in a loop over a minute or so, producing a dynamic Excel display. I want to change the display when a key is pressed, by defining a variable - for example if 'e' is pressed then x = 1

Is there a code to detect a keypress and define a variable with it?

It could be either keypress or keydown event. All the example code I have seen on either will assume it is to reprogramme a keypress or to run a routine.

I looked at code examples and tried Application.OnKey "e", x = 1 No luck there.

Comment: `Application.OnKey "e"` is not totally wrong but you have to define a procedure in your code which will run in case you press an `e`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the value of a variable directly in the `Application.OnKey` statement, it can only call a procedure. However, that procedure can then set the value of the variable. So, for example, `Application.OnKey "e", "SetMyVar"` will call the procedure `SetMyVar` which, in a standard Module, could be:

```
Sub SetMyVar()
    x = 1
End Sub
```

... note it is important to define 'x' at the Module level (ie above all of the Subs and Functions in the Module) in the same Module eg `Dim x As Long` (otherwise your code will not compile if you are using `Option Explicit`).

Then that will do as you ask in your question. A usage example could be (again this in the same Module):

```
Sub MyExistingSubThatUsesX()
    ' this is just a demo Sub and you will use your own Sub to do what you want with the value of x
    If x = 1 Then
        Debug.Print Now, "x is 1"
    Else
        Debug.Print Now, "x is not 1"
    End If
End Sub
```

A few other things.

1. You might find this "e key behavior" a bit frustrating. Anytime you press 'e' (when you are not already typing into a cell) so you might consider using Ctrl+e which would be `Application.OnKey "^e", "SetMyVar"` instead. See [Application.OnKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) for more key combination options.
2. If you want the value of x to alternate between two values then you could (in `SetMyVar`) replace `x = 1` with, for example, `x = 1 - x` then x will alternate between 0 and 1. Obviously you could also use an `If` statement or some other code to set other values for x.
3. You might want to make the "e key behavior" only work when a specific Workbook is open and active. To do this, in the ThisWorkbook Module (must be ThisWorkbook, this won't work in any other Module) add:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    ' set a press of the 'e' key to run the SetMyVar Sub when this Workbook is the active Workbook
    Application.OnKey "e", "SetMyVar"
    Debug.Print Now, "Set"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    ' stop a press of the 'e' key from running the SetMyVar Sub when this Workbook is not the active Workbook
    Application.OnKey "e", ""
    Debug.Print Now, "Stopped"
End Sub
```

... again you can replace "e" with "^e" if you would rather. Now, when you switch to view a different Workbook (or close the Workbook you have added the code to) the "e key behavior" will stop and when you switch back (or re-open) the Workbook you have added the code to then the "e key behavior" will (re-)start.

Comment: I take the point - I have the wrong approach. VBA is for a short macro triggered and over in a moment. I turned that round:  my VBA sub runs in the background, feeding data to show a moving display, on which the changes are defined by integer variables. I am looking for a code that reacts during the runtime to a key being pressed - it will then redefine a variable and so change the way the display changes.

Comment: VBA is 'single-threaded' and so one Sub cannot run while another Sub is in the process of running (if, that is, your Sub does not 'take a break'). The approach you might want to take is for your long-running Sub to periodically check if a key is pressed down ... that is possible, but it's a whole different question with an answer involving the Windows API.

Comment: However, if my answer actually answered your question but you now need to ask another, different, question then please mark my answer as accepted (click the tick/check icon) so that if others have the same question then they can identify that it has a valid answer.